# Imported Blender Texture doesn't look the same as in the original blend file

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, materials

So I downloaded a bunch of Cycles materials to use in Blender. However when I append them to the .blend file I want to use them in they don't look the same as in the original file.

For example here's one for water, in the original .blend file rendered it looks like this: 
[image]

But in a new .blend file with the material appended it looks like this:

[image]

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong? I've been searching the internet for answers for a long time but I just can't find any!

EDIT: It was probably unclear but yes the lighting is different in the second picture how the second picture is also opaque and has no roughness on it while the original is somewhat transparent and has bumps over the surface.

Comment: is the lighting different?

Comment: How can I tell? I feel like there's more to it than that though. The original material is somewhat transparent but the new one is completely opaque

Comment: A material appearance doesn't depend on itself alone. The scene in which it is setup, lighting, environment, other objects influence it.

Comment: I understand that but I don't think there are lights or anything like that set up in either of these. I can't figure out where the differences between the two are. And hints as to where I should try looking in there?

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same issue, you have to uncheck *Ambient Occlusion* in *World* tab

Comment: Hi, thanks for the post. This site is not a regular forum, answers should be substantial and thoroughly explain the solution and required workflow. One liners and short tips rarely make for a good answer. If you can [edit] your post and provide some more details about the procedure and why it works feel free to restore it, otherwise it may be deleted or converted into a comment. Perhaps add a few [images](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963) illustrating the workflow and final results. See [How do I write a good answer?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)